# $x^6-2\varphi^5x^5+2\varphi x+\varphi^6=0$ solving in radicals

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve the equation $x^6-2\varphi^5x^5+2\varphi x+\varphi^6=0$ in radicals using *Mathematica*?

where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Solution is Ramanujan's Class Invariant $G_{125}$, Class Invariant is always algebraic, therefore this equation is solvable in radicals.

I try to use "Solve and Reduce ", but  there is no  "Radical" output

```
  t = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2  

  Solve[x^6 - 2 t^5 x^5 + 2 t x + t^6 == 0, x, Reals]
```

out

```
  {{x -> 1}, {x -> Root[1 - 20 #1 - 45 #1^2 - 70 #1^3 - 95 #1^4 - 118 #1^5 -   95 #1^6 - 70 #1^7 - 45 #1^8 - 20 #1^9 + #1^10 &, 2]}}
```

Comment: @Dr.belisarius Solution is Ramanujan's Class Invariant $G_{125}$.  Class Invariant is always algebraic

Comment: But not every algebraic number has a radical representation.

Comment: @JohnDoty are you sure? could you give me an example?

Comment: See the "polynomial roots" bullet at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number

Comment: @JohnDoty aaah of cource.. Galois theory.. :))

Comment: If I put: `1/64 (1 + Sqrt[5])^6 + (1 + Sqrt[5]) x - 1/16 (1 + Sqrt[5])^5 x^5 + 
  x^6 == 0` to **Maple 2022.2** give me a solution, but is very huge. Solution is with radicals.

Answer (score 8):

Only a partial answer here, but I believe your `Root` object is indeed solvable in radicals. I have no idea how to *find* the solution, but here's how I came to my conclusion.

First let's define the polynomial we're working with:

```
p[x_] := 1 - 20 x - 45 x^2 - 70 x^3 - 95 x^4 - 118 x^5 - 95 x^6 - 70 x^7 - 45 x^8 - 20 x^9 + x^10
```

Get its roots:

```
roots = x /. Solve[p[x] == 0, x];
```

Now we find a generator for the root's splitting field:

```
θ = ToNumberField[roots, All][[1, 1]];
```

Find the degree of the splitting field extension:

```
Exponent[θ[[1]][x], x]
(* 20 *)
```

From this we can find the order of the Galois group:
$$ \left|\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\theta)/\mathbb{Q})\right| = [\mathbb{Q}(\theta) : \mathbb{Q}] = 20. $$

Now there's only 5 groups of order 20 and they're all solvable, so we can stop here, i.e. we can conclude $p(x)$ can be solved in radicals.

p.s. [Here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20)'s info on all groups of order 20. It mentions they are all solvable.

Comment: Maybe cross-list this question with math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @QuantumDot how do I cross list a question?

Comment: I have no idea.  I thought you would know...

Comment: @ChipHurst I think something is wrong here. As can be seen either from above or `Factor[x^6 - 2 t^5 x^5 + 2 t x + t^6 /. t -> GoldenRatio, 
 Extension -> GoldenRatio]`, one factor is of degree 5. If this splits then that split involves algebraic conjugates, which means it splits into subfactors all of the same degree over Q. Or so I believe. With 5 being prime this of course means there can be no such split. (But maybe I'm seeing this all wrong, what with the fog and all.)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Right, but I started off with the degree 10 polynomial that came from the output of `Solve`. I chose this one because it has integer coefficients, whereas the degree 5 polynomial did not.

Comment: Okay, I think I see the point you were getting at. The split will be into linear factors, and involve a radical extension of degree 5 in addition to the quadratic `GoldenRatio`.

Comment: By the way I like that method of figuring the extension degree (so I upvoted). And wipe the L off your forehead, it makes you look gloomy.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well it's a backwards L :P

Answer (score 4):

```
t = (1 + Sqrt[5])/2;

p=x^6 - 2 t^5 x^5 + 2 t x + t^6;
```

---

**Not really an answer** (there is already an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625) ) just mentioning something rather interesting that has an underlying lesson to be wary of generalizations from finite samples. I am also completing the answer in the previous link to explain how one can obtain a fully radical solution.

---

Notice:

```
p // Factor
```

$$-\left((x-1) \left(-x^5+5 \sqrt{5} x^4+10 x^4+5 \sqrt{5} x^3+10 x^3+5 \sqrt{5} x^2+10 x^2+5 \sqrt{5} x+10 x+4 \sqrt{5}+9\right)\right)$$

So that one may focus on the degree 5 irreducible factor:

```
(9 + 4 Sqrt[5] + 10 x + 5 Sqrt[5] x + 10 x^2 + 5 Sqrt[5] x^2 + 10 x^3 + 5 Sqrt[5] x^3 + 10 x^4 + 5 Sqrt[5] x^4 - x^5) //Simplify
```

$$-x^5+5 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) x^4+5 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) x^3+5 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) x^2+5 \left(\sqrt{5}+2\right) x+4 \sqrt{5}+9$$

I used [AskConstants](https://math.hawaii.edu/%7Edale/AskConstants/AskConstants.html) to guess a formula for the unique real root from a numerical approximation. Once that root is factored out, one is left with a degree 4 polynomial which can be solved by radicals.

This is the solution I got from AskConstants:

```
1/(2^(1/4) DedekindEta[(25 I)/2])
```

This solution has a problem which is that one expects a ratio of Dedekind functions. In particular, that is needed to removed the usual $\Gamma(1/4)$ that accompanies these Dedekind eta functions evaluated at imaginary rationals (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101157/1049002) for the case of integers (one of the comments mentions that the formula for $\eta(30i)$ there is false)).

This approximation has a relative error with the exact solution of the order of 10^(-68) when computed with `N[#,100]` ! That is, the approximation has more than 50 correct decimals and the formula is still false !

*The lesson/moral of the story part is over. The next section completes the answers provided in the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2092323/ramanujans-class-invariant-g-625) above*

---

The answer provided in the link for the real root of the quintic factor is:

$$\frac{2^{-1 / 4} \eta^2(\tau)}{\eta\left(\frac{\tau}{2}\right) \eta(2 \tau)}$$

With $\tau=i25=i\sqrt{625}$.

Notice how close AskConstants was. Th missing factor is very close to 1:

```
(η[τ])^2/η[2 τ] /. η -> 
DedekindEta /. τ -> Sqrt[-25^2] // N[#, 80] &
```

`(* 0.999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999987915955843352 *)`

$\eta(i25)$ can be found in the particular values section of `MathematicalFunctionData[DedekindEta]["Dataset"]`.

$\eta(2\times 25 i)$ can be found in the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3101157/1049002) (I recall that there is a comment that there is a mistake for $\eta(i 30)$ so maybe verify numerically first (I did not check)). The main issue is $\eta(i 25/2)$ which I did not find in my search. This can be derived form the reasoning below.

Denoting $R$ the Rogers-Ramunajan continued fraction and $q=e^{2i\pi\tau}$, the following formula from wikipedia [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction#cite_note-1) (I also searched for the source referenced for the formula):

$$\frac{1}{R(q)}-R(q) = \frac{\eta(\frac{\tau}{5})}{\eta(5\tau)}+1$$

can be used.

Indeed, for $\tau=\frac{5i}{2}$ one has:

$$\frac{1}{R(e^{-5\pi})}-R(e^{-5\pi}) = \frac{\eta(\frac{i}{2})}{\eta(\frac{25i}{2})}+1$$

The formula for $R(e^{-5\pi})$ is given in the same wikipedia page and involves the golden ratio. $\eta(\frac{i}{2})$ is given in this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function#Special_values.

The final result with all 6 roots might have a rather interesting computational graph given both the complexity and simplicity of the result.

Comment: You do understand algebraic numbers may be roots of a quintic and that does not have (generally, that is, some do have) radical representation?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников yes why ? The question mentions "therefore this equation is solvable in radicals" the other answer says that it is solvable by radicals, and the title mentions that they would like a solution in radicals.

Comment: "Class Invariant is always algebraic, therefore this equation is solvable in radicals." That is false. Abel–Ruffini.

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников indeed I did not bother much with the deduction given in the question but in any case the other answer mentioned that the solution is indeed solvable by radicals. Still I am not sure why you wrote your initial comment given that the answer provided here gives the steps for constructing the roots by radicals and the other answer already confirmed that the roots can be found by radicals.

Comment: That answer just says "It's too long to describe step-by-step the method to solve solvable quintics." And other answer here just says "but I believe your Root object is indeed solvable in radicals".

Comment: Your last comment still does not describe the intention of your first comment. Your first comment is written in a condescendant manner assuming that I am unaware of the impossibility of solving certain quintics whereas my answer does not assume that. If you do not know the knowledge background of someone then assume the most not the least. Your comments have not provided any interesting new knowledge to me and are written in an attacking tone so there is no point in continuing the discussion.

Comment: Where can you look up order 20 group solutions?

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников Here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_20

Comment: There are no solutions there. Soluble group is by definition in radicals. Maybe it was just proven it was soluble but no solution in the papers?