# Does Solve[] find ALL the exact roots of rational polynomials?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Does Solve[] find ALL the exact roots of rational polynomials?

I've done a bunch of tests where I created an expression with some analytic roots, and Solve[] always found them all.  But is the failure of Solve[] to find any analytic roots conclusive proof that none exist?

```
expr = (12 x - 29)*(31 x + 113)*(501 x - Prime[28])*(x^4 - 7 x^2 + 1001 x - 20)*(1001*x^5 + 47*x^4 + x^3 + 91*x^2 + 144 x - 1001) //Expand;
Solve[expr == 0, x]
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading the question, but polynomials of degree > 1 always have a root (FTA).

Comment: @MichaelE2  I'm asking specifically about analytically expressible roots.  All n roots of an n-th order polynomial are analytically expressible if n<5, but if n>=5, there might not be any analytical solutions.  Solve[] leaves those solutions in Root[] form.

Comment: @MichaelE2  For example, if you run Solve[Sum[x^n, {n, 0, 4}] + 1 == 0, x], you'll get analytical expressions for each of the four solutions, which are all irrational.  If you change the 4 to a 5, you'll get none.

Comment: By "analytically expressible", I take it you mean expressible "in terms of (only) radicals"?  (That is, not just any exact analytic or symbolic expression.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  I don't believe polynomials have any exact solutions other than rational solutions and solutions in terms of radicals.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html, equations (7) - (11), and so forth.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Okay, you got me.  What I said only applies to polynomials with rational coefficients.  If I change the title to "Does Solve[] find all the exact roots of rational polynomials?" will that clear it up?

Comment: In my experience, the standard phrase has been "solvable by radicals."  (At least, that's what I think you're talking about.)

Comment: @MichaelE2  Sooo, do you maybe know the answer to my question?   :-)

Comment: I didn't know the answer, but looking at Wikipedia, I found this example: `x^5 + 20 x^3 + 20 x^2 + 30 x + 10 /. x -> Surd[2, 5] - Surd[2, 5]^2 + Surd[2, 5]^3 - Surd[2, 5]^4 // FullSimplify` and `Solve[x^5 + 20 x^3 + 20 x^2 + 30 x + 10 == 0, x]`.  So I guess the answer is "no," `Solve` does not always find solutions in terms of radicals when they exist. Does it seem so to you?

Comment: @MichaelE2  Well, I couldn't find a counter-example, but you just gave me one.  If you copy that into an Answer I can Accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the answer is "no," `Solve` does not always find solutions in terms of radicals when they exist.

Example:  The polynomial $x^5 + 20 x^3 + 20 x^2 + 30 x + 10$ has root expressible in terms of radicals (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Other_solvable_quintics)):

```
poly = x^5 + 20 x^3 + 20 x^2 + 30 x + 10;
x1 = 2^(1/5) - 2^(2/5) + 2^(3/5) - 2^(4/5);
poly /. x -> x1 // Simplify
(*  0  *)
```

But `Solve` returns only `Root` objects:

```
Solve[poly == 0, x]
(*
  {{x -> Root[10 + 30 #1 + 20 #1^2 + 20 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 1]}, 
   ...,
   {x -> Root[10 + 30 #1 + 20 #1^2 + 20 #1^3 + #1^5 &, 5]}}
*)
```

Applying [`ToRadicals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToRadicals.html) does not convert `Root` to radicals.  However all roots may be expressed in terms of radicals, as may be seen by executing the following:

```
deflation = PolynomialReduce[poly, {x - x1}, x][[1, 1]]
Solve[deflation == 0, x]
(* long expression in radicals omitted *)
```

They may be compared to the original `Root` objects with

```
(x /. Solve[poly == 0, x]) -
   Join[{x1}, x /. Solve[deflation == 0, x]] // FullSimplify
(*  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you, even though I was hoping the answer would be yes.    :-(

Comment: In fact it's not trivial determining if a polynomial's root can even be expressed in terms of radicals. One needs to find its Galois group. See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103593/4346).

Comment: [Here's](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/158/Radical.nb?file_id=41) a package to solve quintics in radicals (when possible).