# How to convert a polynomial into monic form of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, group-theory

The function `ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"]` can get a **Galois Group** about *a monic irreducible integer polynomial*. But I want to know the **Galois Group** about a non-monic polynomial, such as:$$5 x^5 + 6 x + 6$$So how to convert it into a monic form of a polynomial and **keeps its Galois Group unchanged** by *MMA*?

Comment: You can use Sage from within Mathematica to compute it.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Can you teach me how to call sage to solve it in MMA?

Comment: By the way, what is wrong with using `ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"][5 x^5 + 6 x + 6, x]`?

Comment: @azerbajdzan `ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"]` tell me its Galois Group of 
 the polynomial is $S(5)$, is wrong, actually its Galois Group is $F(5)$

Comment: Sage labels it as `C5 : C4` or `SmallGroup(20,3)`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Yes, [maple also is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueF3x.jpg), the documentation of `StauduharGaloisGroup` show it just work in *monic irreducible integer polynomial*. So I want to convert is into monic form

Comment: galois still requires at least rational arguments, while Mathematica does not require even that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103573/x6-2-varphi5x52-varphi-x-varphi6-0-solving-in-radicals/277726?noredirect=1#comment693703_277726

Comment: @azerbajdzan Done! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we hope to keep the *Galois Group* unchanged, we should find a *Algebraic Integer* in the current field. We have two method to do this:

```
sols5 = SolveValues[5 x^5 + 6 x + 6 == 0, x];
n = First[sols5];
```

### First Method

```
poly = MinimalPolynomial[AlgebraicNumberDenominator[n]*n, x]
```

> 3750 + 750 x + x^5

### Second Method

```
poly = MinimalPolynomial[NumberFieldIntegralBasis[n].RandomInteger[1, 5],x]
```

> 5400 + 1080 x - 540 x^2 + x^5

Now, the `ResourceFunction["StauduharGaloisGroup"]` works well.